# Search In Sharepoint site

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How to give double quotes in `q="xx yy"`? It is working for single quotes.

I need the file which exactly matches the given word side by side

```
/sites/{site-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
```

For example:

```js
var filesUri = https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drive/search(q=\"xx yy\")
```

```js
var encodedUrl = encodeURI(filesUri);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: encodedUrl,
    contentType: "aapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    }
}).done(function (response) {
    alert("Successfully fetched files from sharepoint.");
    var items = response.value;
}).fail(function (ex) {
    alert("Fetching files from SharePoint failed." + ex);
});
```

the api request is not working error given below

> Syntax error: character '\"' is not valid at position 2 in 'q=\"xx yy\"'.",

Comment: You post javascript code in a SharePoint question yet you tag with [tag:c#], [tag:asp.net] and [tag:microsoft-graph]? I wonder how this question is related to any of those technologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-quotes (`"`) are not supported, you need to use single-quotes (`'`):

```
/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drive/search(q='xx yy')
```

Comment: when we give search keyword in single quotes, the document which contains both 'xx'  'yy'   are retrieved .it is not necessary to be a phrase.i need it to be a phrase.

Comment: You cannot control search in this way. By default it will attempt to order the results so that those that more accurately match your query will surface first. There isn't however a way to do Google/Bing style query augmentation.